# Lombok Annotations not processing in tests - Bazel

Tags: java, testing, bazel, lombok, annotation-processing

I am trying to use Lombok for a project along with Bazel. The Lombok annotations are not resolved in the test files. Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

I have enabled the Lombok Plugin and Annotation Processing in IntelliJ

```
java_library(
    name = "lombok",
    exports = [
        "@maven//:org_projectlombok_lombok",
    ],
    exported_plugins = [
        ":lombok_plugin"
    ],
)

java_plugin(
    name = "lombok_plugin",
    processor_class = "lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor",
    deps = [
        ":lombok_jar",
    ],
)

java_import(
    name = "lombok_jar",
    jars = [
      "@maven//:v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.20/lombok-1.18.20.jar"
    ],
)
```

Thanks

Comment: it may be related to the recent changes shipped with version 4, for more info:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/12837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable header compilation for lombok objects to work across targets - add the below snippet in .bazelrc

```
# See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/12837.
build --nojava_header_compilation
test --nojava_header_compilation
```